# Why does TurnKey Linux not have sudo installed by default, if you're never supposed to login as root?

Tags: sudo, turnkey

As I understand the `sudo` command (and maybe I'm wrong) it's a way to run what you need to run as root, and then get out as quickly as possible.  But I read in the forums for TurnKey Linux that they believe you do not need `sudo` on a server machine.  This seems wrong to me, since you're never supposed to stay logged in as root; what am I missing here?

Comment: Jeremy addressed this [on this askubuntu post](http://askubuntu.com/a/94023/212231). Quote: `With this setup [server], sudo is generally not required. For general admin just use root (and so no need for sudo). If you want additional users you probably don't want them having admin (sudo) privileges anyway. [...] If you want sudo then just install it.`

Answer (score 3):

When people say "Don't login as root", the primary target of this (as I've seen it) is against people that use root as if it were a normal user account.  For example logging into X and running your DE/WM as root along with every app you run.  This is bad, don't login as root!

In the absence of `sudo` the way to elevate to superuser privileges is with `su`.  I would also argue for a server with multiple users that `su` is a better choice than `sudo` for unrestricted root access.  This is because `su` requires the root password, wheras `sudo` makes use of the user's password.  This means if users have `sudo` access and their account password is compromised then the attacker now also can run commands as root.  This is a bad thing.

For a server environment `sudo` only has a place (in my opinion) if you need to grant access to specific superuser commands to users that you do not trust with root access (e.g. *not* unrestricted access).  I'd argue on a production server users like this don't exist and root access should be restricted to the administrators.